# The advantage of enumerators over collections

Tags: ruby

I don't see the use of enumerators. Dave Thomas' book states this:

> Enumerator allows you to capture the concept of an enumeration as an object. This allows you to store enumerations in variables, pass them as parameters, and so on.

But I can also assign arrays to variables, pass arrays as arguments and so on. In fact, I think using a regular iterator with a collection like array is more concise than using an enumerator:

```
str = "quick brown fox"
str.scan(/\w+/).each {|w| puts w }
quick
brown
fox
```

vs.

```
str = "quick brown fox"
enum = str.to_enum(:scan, /\w+/)
enum.each { |w| puts w }
quick
brown
fox
```

The enum version requires an extra step and produces the same result. When is it more practical to use an enum over a collection with iterator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using an Enumerator makes some things possible that Arrays don't allow.

An Enumerator can represent a sequence that is lazily evaluated, meaning the code to generate an element doesn't get run until the element is needed.

That means that an Enumerator can represent an infinite sequence.  For example:

```
e = Enumerator.new { |y| s = 'a'; loop { y << s = s.succ } }
e.first(5)  # => ["b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
```

This example shows an infinite sequence, which implies it has to be lazily evaluated because your computer is finite.  But even if you aren't working with infinite sequences, the lazy evaluation can still be very helpful for saving CPU time.

Also, an Enumerator can be used an external iterator, which provides all sorts of flexibility in how you use it.  (See 7stud's answer for an example.)

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: @JohnMerino, `e = [1, 2, 3].cycle
p e.first(10)`

Answer (score 2):

Enumerators are also *external* iterators, which allows you to iterate over two arrays at once:

```
e1 = [1, 2, 3].each
e2 = ['a', 'b', 'c'].each

loop do
  num, ch = e1.next, e2.next
  puts "#{num} -> #{ch}"
end

--output:--
1 -> a
2 -> b
3 -> c
```

When an Enumerator runs out of items, it raises a StopIteration exception, and loop() automatcially catches that exception and terminates.

Comment: The thing you are doing here could be accomplished with an array and an index integer that increases, but an Enumerator allows us to write it so much more succinctly.

Comment: Wow!  So that is the first reason I've found to use `loop` instead of `while`!